# disable non-prefix matching in company mode

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I am a new user just turned from auto-complete to company mode. In auto-complete mode, I use tab key to start completion, when there're no characters at all, the tab key will behave as usual, i.e. indent this line. But in company mode, whenever I type 'tab', it will automacilly shows the completion popup window, so I cannot use tab to indent. How can I solve this problem?

By the way, I also want the completion starts when I type ::,-> and . in C++ mode. The backend is irony mode. I add the next line in my init file ,but it doesn't work at all:
(add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'company-irony-setup-begin-commands)

Another problem is that does company realize the case insensitive matching? For example, I want to complete a variable named aBigApple, I just need to type 'abig' .

Comment: The original poster should have been advised to limit him / herself to just one (1) question per post. The original poster should also have been advised that this particular forum is primarily geared towards resolving a specific coding / programming issue -- e.g., provide a sample code that is not quite doing what it is supposed to do, and specify the desired effect and what is happening instead. The original poster could also have been advised that the Emacs Beta site has participants who are more receptive to newcomers:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/  Please be kind and helpful to newbies.